# Cannot have bootstrap navbar and carousel in page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Inteenships</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Zilla+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Inteenships</a>
      </div>

      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>





  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>



    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="..." alt="Picture 1">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>
            Picture 1
          </h1>
          <p>
            Nothing Special
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="..." alt="Picture 2">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>
            Picture 2
          </h1>
          <p>
            Nothing Special
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="..." alt="Picture 3">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>
            Picture 3
          </h1>
          <p>
            Nothing Special
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <a href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous Slide</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next Slide</span>
    </a>



  </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to have a bootstrap navbar and carousel on my home page but the carousel does not appear when I load it. If I get rid of the navbar, the carousel appears but in the location of where the navbar would be. Are there any errors in my code? I only have a reset style in my css:

```
*{
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }
```

This doesn't affect anything however. Is there anything that I need to remove or add in order to get this working?

Additional question: I am fairly new to html/css. What is the point of a div with a class of container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navbar will have position: fixed; so give padding top to your body.

```
body{ padding-top: 51px}
```

51px is height of your navbar.

container is a bootstrap class which has fixed width(different widths at different resolutions) and margin left and right auto, it will align div having class container to center by giving equal space to left and right.

Comment: I have another concern... is there a way to slide the carousel down when the navbar collapses?

Comment: slide the carousel down ? you mean move to down.
also when navbar collapses means below 767 resolution ?

Comment: let me rephrase.. when the navbar collapses (and produces a dropdown on toggle), I want the carousel to move down so that the user can see the whole thing... and the navbar dropdown options.

Answer (score 0):

.navbar-fixed-top make navbar's position fixed which doesn't count when your carousel's position:relative. so add some margin or padding on carousel class's or remove .navbar-fixed-top class.

```
.carousel
{
   margin-top:60px;
}
```